# Target Audience does not work with site SharePoint groups for XSLT List View web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt-list-view-web-part, audience-targeting

On some xsltlistview web parts, whenever I try to set the target audience to use one of the SharePoint site groups (These are groups created when you create a new site), it tells me that it does not recognize the group. However, it works for groups that I've personally created through the browser.

Please help....

Comment: Are these groups that you are searching in the same site collection?

Comment: Yes, there are in the same site collection.

Comment: Could you post some code or more explicit example please?

Comment: Are these site groups being created automatically by a workflow when sites are deployed? You could try going in to the group details screen and re-save to see if that registers them by forcing them through the default SharePoint screens. Do they become available later on (i.e. perhaps after the Audience compilation process has run)?

Comment: @foocode these kind of audiences (Groups) are not compiled like "real" audience rules

Comment: @foocode I have not run the 'Audience compilation process'. Why would it? The gorup that I'm referring to is a normal OOTB SharePoint group created by SharePoint when the site is created.